Can I use a Pi as a file server - with 2@16tB hard drives?
I would like to replace a failing Windows desktop that I use for backups. It has 2 @ 16tB drives attached and I backup over WiFi.
I am looking for a cheap NAS alternative. Would a Pi 5 do the job? I see lots of articles about using the Pi as a file server, but nothing above 2tB

your question is about using a linux computer to build a NAS

Yes - a Raspberry Pi 5 can be  configured to serve as a NAS. In fact, there are so many options for accomplishing this that it complicates the answer! - especially since you've not provided much detail in your question.
One part of your question I can answer definitively is WRT your comment, "... nothing above 2tB". Your 2 16TB drives will not be mounted in the same way your SD card is mounted, so you need not be concerned over the 2TB limit.
Given the absence of details in your Question, the best that can be done is to describe a generic approach:
1. Power:
You will likely want to power your drives from a separate power supply or USB Hub.
2. HDD Interface?
Are these SATA drives - or USB drives - or something else? You need to get a handle on that as this will determine many of the options available to you.
3. "Packaging":
You can leave your drives "loose", or you can mount them on a HAT, or you can buy a housing for your drives, or ...  Many options available here!
4. The file system for your 16TB drives
I don't know much about Windows these days, but I'll guess that if your drives have been in use with a Windows system the drives are formatted with NTFS. That's not a great choice for a NAS - IMHO. You might consider btrfs or zfs. Alternatively, you would probably be fine with the Linux default filesystem ext4. Note that ext4 is limited to 16TB per file system, but this need not be a concern as you can create as many ext4 filesystems as you need!
There are other file systems supported by Linux. And there are many online articles available to help you choose one.
Again, it's difficult to give specific answers to non-specific questions, but I hope this has helped. For more details, I'd recommend you read through the links above, and then consult one of the many detailed how-to's. Here's a search to help you get started, and here are three articles that appear competent: 1, 2, 3.

Yes, but the drives needs a USB adapter each and you need to supply enough power for both the pi and the two drives
Unless you enjoy tinkering a dedicated device like a synology with room for the drives may be a better choice.

I agree!...  but he did specify "cheap"  :)

@Seamus I don’t consider a 5 cheap

I don't either, but it is "cheap" compared to a new Synology box  :)
